# Confirm that two rows have data

Tags: r

If I have a table such as the following

```
> dput(Stackoverflowexcelexample)
structure(list(Column.1 = c("Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", 
"Row 5", "Row 6", "Row 7", "Row 8", "Row 9", "Row 10", "Row 11"
), Column.2 = c("data", "data", "data", "data", "data", "data", 
"data", "data", "data", "data", "data"), Column.3 = c(42989, 
42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 42989, 
42989), Column.4 = c(3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), Column.5 = c(1, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Column.6 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Column.7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Column.8 = c("data here", NA, NA, NA, NA, "data here", NA, 
NA, "data here", "data here", "data here"), Column.9 = c(42986, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 42983, NA, NA, 42983, 42985, 42983)), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

(Note: the values such as 42989 are `dates`)

How can I confirm that if there is a value in a row of `Column 8`, there must be a `date`value in `Column 9`and vice versa?  I think it should be in an `if`statement, but I´m not sure.

Expected output

Let's assume that this is given: [image: This is given.]

where in Row 5 there is a 'date' in column 9 and NA in column 8.

then it should print to the console ("Missing Value")

```
source('~/examplescript.R')
[1] "Missing Value"
```

If there is data in column 8 row 5 but no date in column 9, it should print Missing Date.

```
source('~/examplescript.R')
[1] "Missing Date"
```

Please note: Row 5 was just an example row. This should apply to any row, but only print the expected output once.

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you after a logical vector? i.e.`rowSums(is.na(df[8:9])) == 0`

Comment: @Sotos  I´ve added the expected output.  So for example if in Column 9 Row 2 there is a date, but in column 8 row 2 there is not text, I want it to print out ("Missing Value")

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple `ifelse` statement in combination with 'rowSums'. The idea is simple and states that if there are no NAs then the sum of NAs will be 0, i.e.

```
ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[8:9])) > 0, 'Missing Value', 'Valid Data')

#                  1               2               3               4               5               6               7               8 
#       "Valid Data" "Missing Value" "Missing Value" "Missing Value" "Missing Value"    "Valid Data" "Missing Value" "Missing Value" 
#                 9              10              11 
#       "Valid Data"    "Valid Data"    "Valid Data"
```

Another output could be,

```
paste0('value: ', ifelse(is.na(df$Column.8), 'Missing Value', 'Valid'), ' - Date: ', ifelse(is.na(df$Column.9), 'Missing Date', 'Valid'))
 #[1] "value: Valid - Date: Valid"                "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date" "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date"
 #[4] "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date" "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date" "value: Valid - Date: Valid"               
 #[7] "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date" "value: Missing Value - Date: Missing Date" "value: Valid - Date: Valid"               
#[10] "value: Valid - Date: Valid"                "value: Valid - Date: Valid"
```

Comment: I think I wasn´t completely clear.  I wanted it to print to the console Missing value or missing date.  so something like: if (!statement that confirms that if one then the other){print("Missing")}

Comment: oh ok, let me revise

Comment: Great. Thanks @Sotos.

Comment: Have a look and let me know

Comment: Let me clarify again (I am so sorry), if ANY of them are missing one or the other, I just want one message to be printed.  It will go in a series of if statements.

Comment: One message for the whole data frame? Not a message per row? Or a message per row IF there are missing? Please add the expected output exactly as you need it in your question. Don't just describe the output...add what you expect to see for your example.

Comment: One message for the whole data frame if any of the outputs are missing.  I've added a much clearer example to the questions